# How to I attach & detach parts of human heart in VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Is there an Unity asset for human heart where I can do stuff with parts of heart? I also checked the unity asset store but all seem to have the human heart as a whole. If not, what should be my next steps? I'm using Oculus Quest.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try first is to make your own "heart" by just stacking some blocks together and make sure you have the code and functionality work first. Making something visually pleasing should not be the first priority.